# Fetching document with a List<Map> type field from Collection in MongoDb using Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am saving a list of Map in a collection. It is getting saved as Array of object on Mongo.
But when a find query is triggered from Morphia it throws null pointer exception. Here I am using Map and so I think there is no need of using any converter as it is already there in morphia library.
While debugging the API, found out that

```
public Object decode(final Class c, final Object fromDBObject) {
        return decode(c, fromDBObject, null);
    }
```

is called from DefaultConverters and this method in turn finds what converter to call and MapOfValuesConverter is called and null pointer is thrown because of this null value passed from DefaultConverters class.

But i am unable to find what is causing the problem.

My Entity class is like :

```
@Entity(value = "entity", noClassnameStored = true)
class Entity{
   @Id
   private long id;
   @Property
   private List<Map> listOfMap; 
 }
```

Primary key finder is like :

```
badgeDraftDao.findOne("_id", id)
```

Any help will be highly appriciated.

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createMap(DefaultCreator.java:105) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.MapOfValuesConverter.decode(MapOfValuesConverter.java:40) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.decode(DefaultConverters.java:222) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.decode(DefaultConverters.java:226) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.IterableConverter.decode(IterableConverter.java:53) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:134) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:27) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:604) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:585) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:296) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:78) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:65) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:60) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:415) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.findOne(BasicDAO.java:194) ~[morphia-0.107.jar:na]
    at in.til.tp.core.service.impl.BadgeDraftServiceImpl.findByPrimaryKey(BadgeDraftServiceImpl.java:26) ~[TimespointsV2-core-1.0.jar:na]
    at in.til.ssm.controller.badges.BadgeViewController.createBadgeStep2(BadgeViewController.java:70) ~[BadgeViewController.class:na]
    at in.til.ssm.controller.badges.BadgeViewController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1944c197.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640) ~[spring-aop-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at in.til.ssm.controller.badges.BadgeViewController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c7c54e3_2.createBadgeStep2(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:439) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:178) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, it looks like you answered your own question, the 3rd param which is null is causing the NPE. You need to specify the converter explicitly in this case - you can use the MapOfValuesConverter from their library.

Comment: Also, when posting about an error, it's helpful to include the stacktrace so we can see where the error actually occurred.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply.@tinker I am not using my custom pojo using Map only and MapOfValuesConverter is already getting called. But throwing error.
@evanchooly : Included the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Well, bad news and good news.  You've hit a limitation in Morphia's mapping logic in 0.110 and so that entity won't work.  The good news is, I have a fix that will be in 0.111 coming soon.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort .. I managed to make it working by using Embedded on the field and it worked. And thing its kinda hack because Embedded is meant for other Entity. Will wait for new morphia release..

Answer (score 0):

I verify the fix for this problem, but when I removed the `@Property` annotation, it threw another exception. More details in my comment in a very identical issue that I filed earlier:
https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/718